# insert query through php doesn't update MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

I have user input coming in from a form (possible null fields - yes, the database is set up to work with null values), and I need to insert the information into a table in the database.

Just some more information: I'm making this application in Titanium

This is the code that sends all the parameters to the PHP file:

```
saveButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    var url = ""; //url is in here; I just took it out for privacy
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    var params = {
        query : "enterAsset",
        barcode : barcodeTextField.value, //all these textfields are editable by the user
        assetClass : assetClassTextField.value,
        manufacturer : manufacturerTextField.value,
        model : modelTextField.value,
        serialNum : serialNumTextField.value,
        custodian : custodianTextField.value,
        status : statusTextField.value,
        loginName : LOGIN_NAME,
        divisionID : DIVISION_ID,
        dateBuy : dateBoughtTextField.value,
        priceBuy : priceTextField.value,
        dateInSvc : dateInServiceTextField.value,
        dateLastSvc : dateLastServiceTextField.value,
    };
    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert("Successful entry"); //this alert does appear when the button is pressed
    };
    xhr.send(params);
});
```

This is the code in the PHP file after connecting to the database:

```
$query = $_GET['query'];

switch($query)  { //this switch statement exists so we can access the database for multiple queries from the same .php file. We know it works because the "login" query works just fine.
    case "data":
        //unimportant stuff is in here
        break;
    case "clients":
        //more irrelevant stuff in here
        break;
    case "login": //this works, but it's not trying to insert anything
        $username = $_GET['username'];  
        $password = $_GET['password'];  
        $stmt4 = $con->prepare('CALL Get_user_auth(:username,:password)');
        $stmt4->bindParam(':username',$username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt4->bindParam(':password',$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt4->execute();
                $results = $stmt4->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt4->closeCursor();
        break;
    case "search":
        //more irrelevant stuff in here
        break;
    case "enterAsset":
        $barcode = '12345';
        $assetClass = 'test';
        $manufacturer = 'test';
        $model = 'test';
        $serialNum = 'test';
        $custodian = 'test';
        $locationID = '1';
        $status = 'test';
        $dateBuy = 'test';
        $priceBuy = 'test';
        $dateInSvc = 'test';
        $dateLastSvc = 'test';
        $loginName = 'jane';
        $divisionID = '1';

        $stmt6 = $con->prepare('CALL Enter_new_asset(:divisionID,:barcode,:assetClass,:manufacturer,:model,:serialNum,:custodian,:status,:locationID,:dateBuy,:priceBuy,:dateInSvc,:dateLastSvc,:loginName)');
        $stmt6->bindParam(':divisionID',$divisionID,PDO::PARAM_INT,11);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':barcode',$barcode,PDO::PARAM_STR,128);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':assetClass',$assetClass,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':manufacturer',$manufacturer,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':model',$model,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':serialNum',$serialNum,PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':custodian',$custodian,PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':locationID',$locationID,PDO::PARAM_INT,11);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':dateBuy',$dateBuy,PDO::PARAM_STR,13);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':priceBuy',$priceBuy,PDO::PARAM_STR,10);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':dateInSvc',$dateInSvc,PDO::PARAM_STR,13);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':dateLastSvc',$dateLastSvc,PDO::PARAM_STR,13);
        $stmt6->bindParam(':loginName',$loginName,PDO::PARAM_STR,20);

        $stmt6->execute();
        $stmt6->closeCursor();
        break;
    default:
        $results = "FAIL.";
        break;
}
```

This returns "null" when I specify the "enterAsset" query, which is expected because it shouldn't be returning anything.

The stored query for Enter_new_asset is:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_ASSET_DATA (Division_ID, Barcode_Tag, Asset_Class, Manufacturer, Model, Serial_Num, Custodian, Status, Location_ID, Date_buy, Price_buy, Date_in_svc, Date_last_svc, Updated_by)
VALUES(divisionID,barcode, assetClass, manufacturer, model, serialNum, custodian, status, locationID, dateBuy, priceBuy, dateInSvc, dateLastSvc, loginName)
```

**EDIT:** I tried hardcoding in some values for the variables, and now I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '';' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /homepages/21/d265224452/htdocs/brillient_wordpress/AMproxy.php on line 90

This is the code at line 90:

```
    $stmt6 = $con->prepare('CALL Enter_new_asset(:divisionID,:barcode,:assetClass,:manufacturer,:model,:serialNum,:custodian,:status,:locationID,:dateBuy,:priceBuy,:dateInSvc,:dateLastSvc,:loginName)');
```

My question is: Why is the database not updating with the entered information? A new entry is not appearing in the TBL_ASSET_DATA. Other questions with this issue seem to be using MySQLi or the deprecated mysql commands, and this is using PDO.

Thank you for your help in advance.

**EDIT** I got my database to update by replacing

```
$stmt6 = $con->prepare('CALL Enter_new_asset(:divisionID,:barcode,:assetClass,:manufacturer,:model,:serialNum,:custodian,:status,:locationID,:dateBuy,:priceBuy,:dateInSvc,:dateLastSvc,:loginName)');
```

with:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TBL_ASSET_DATA(Division_ID, Barcode_Tag, Asset_Class, Manufacturer, Model, Serial_Num, Custodian, Status, Location_ID, Date_buy, Price_buy, Date_in_svc, Date_last_svc, Updated_by) VALUES(:divisionID,:barcode, :assetClass, :manufacturer, :model, :serialNum, :custodian, :status, :locationID, :dateBuy, :priceBuy, :dateInSvc, :dateLastSvc, :loginName)";
$stmt6 = $con->prepare($sql);
```

but I'm wondering whether this is secure.

Comment: Are you getting any errors from PDO?

Comment: You don't need the array parameter to execute - that is what the bindParam bit is for.

Comment: No errors from PDO that I can see.
I got rid of the array parameter, and it still isn't updating the database.

Comment: @MikeBrant I tried hard coding in some values for the various fields, and now I'm getting an error that reads: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '';' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /homepages/21/d265224452/htdocs/brillient_wordpress/AMproxy.php on line 90

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a quote to close your string here:

```
$dateLastSvc = 'test;
```

This is making you code behave incorrectly.  You can easily pick ushc typo errors if using an editor with context highlighting.  For example, I could pick this up right away in looking at the highlighting that even Stack Overflow does.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but even after correcting that my database is not being updated.